# How can I proof my IP address?

Tags: tcp, dns, ip, ip-address, wan

If I connect directly to another computer, I proof my IP. But what if I want to receive a message on paper which proofs someones IP?

For example, client contacts Google for an JSON web signature, prints it out on paper, gives the paper to me, and I can verify the signature of the message containing their IP, without ever connecting over to the client (or to Google) by TCP.

Is there a simpeler or better scheme possible?

Comment: What is the use case for validating the IP address?

Answer (score 0):

If you use encryption, consider using [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).  If not, then a simple hash or random number is fine for trivial use, as long as it is unique for a given period of time and then expires.  Either way, you can send the generated value across both transports so they can be matched to each other.  Preferably the server should generate the value to ensure its authenticity, eg:

*"Hello TCP client, send me XXX and your IP over the other transport".*

*"Hello transport client, I see you sent me value XXX and IP YYY, I have a matching TCP client".*

Also keep in mind that if your TCP client is behind a router, the other party is going to see your router's public IP, not your client's private IP behind the router.  So your client will have to send the router's IP, and maybe also send its private IP as well.  Depends on your actual needs.

I don't really see the need to validate the IP, though.  Just dealing with the router situation, let alone trying to avoid IP spoofing, makes it almost not worth doing.  Just having an authenticated token should be good enough.

**Update:** If that is not what you want, then you have to include the IP as part of the encryption/hash.  The client takes some seed values (sometimes known as *nonce* values) and its IP and hashes them all together, then the result is given to the other party.  That party uses the same seed/nonce values and the IP it wants to validate and hashes them together and sees if it comes up with the same result.  If so, the IPs match.

Comment: With your solution I still have to connect to the TCP client?